# ProxyPassReverse Not Working with 302 Redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, redirect, proxypass

I'm using Apache HTTPD to proxy a local Tomcat server:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Everything works fine except when I have a 302 redirect.
For some reason the ProxyPassReverse doesn't rewrite the localhost:8080 and the client gets redirected to localhost:8080 which causes a browser error.

How can I get ProxyPassReverse to work with 302 redirects?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi, can you share your conf? I'm facing the same issue, and the ProxyPreserveHost has not solved it. Thanks